# Mounting Linux FS in Windows 10 using SSHFS

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, server, client

I don't exactly remember how my friend synched his changes in VS Code with remote machine(Gitlab). He commits, adds, changes the code in VS Code and it automatically applied to remote machine.

The problem is I don't remember exactly remaining part but ssh**XYZ** **userid@server**
I don't remember the part **XYZ** but I know that  ssh is secure encrypted connection to the remote server but I don't know the ssh**XYZ**

Comment: Maybe your friend was using the [Remote - SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) extension on VS Code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. Actually, **XYZ** for 'fs' if in total then **sshfs** command.
Here is how to install it:

1. Install the latest version of [WinFsp](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases/tag/v1.2POST1).
2. Install the latest version of [SSHFS-Win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/releases/tag/v3.5.20357). Choose the x64 or x86 installer according to your computer’s architecture.
3. Map Windows Drive using this URL: \sshfs\username@machine_ip....

Author of the following instructions can be found [here](https://medium.com/@danielmarinomirallestaset/mounting-linux-fs-in-windows-10-using-sshfs-e29c7ca81c87)

Comment: The URL, more precise, the URI, actually, the [UNC path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths), should be ```\\sshfs\username@machine_ip...``` (double backslashes).

Comment: WinFsp members have built a website for better user experience: https://winfsp.dev/ .

Comment: e.g. to mount / with ssh key:
`net use k: \\sshfs.kr\user@host/`

see https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win?tab=readme-ov-file#unc-syntax